# Accessible source of social network chat data

Tags: data-request, nlp

Are there any accessible source(s) of **actual chatting text between users of any social network**? There exist other conversational corpora (for instance, the Berkeley Restaurant Project corpus is one). But what I am looking for is the access to a data source from a normal social networking site/app (similar to Facebook, Skype, etc.) that includes the conversation history of its users (with unique ids for users to differentiate them). Essentially, it will be the text that the users (within that particular social network) themselves write in their chat boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the below link to some conversational data sources, may not be facebook, whatsapp etc but should do.

http://freeconnection.blogspot.co.uk/2016/04/conversational-datasets-for-train.html

Comment: [NUS SMS chat dataset](http://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/entrepreneurship/innovation/osr/corpus/) is exactly the kind of dataset I was looking for. The average number of messages per user is quite low though (10000 messages/ 729 unique users) :(